# How to calculate the time in background and make SKAction jump to the time after

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I am working on an app based on sprite kit. I know that all actions will be paused while the app is in background. However, I am doing the fading color thing so I want to calculate the time while the app is in background and make the SKAction which is the fading action jump the time after so that it doesn't look like the color is not changing while the app is in background. So can someone give me some detailed walkthrough about how to do so? Thanks so much!!

Comment: if this is only a visual effect, just set a random color when returning from background - no one will notice ;)

Answer (score 0):

EDITED after rmaddy's suggestion.
In the View Controller that gets opened when the app becomes active, you can directly subscribe to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` to get notified when the app enters or exits foreground.

```
 @property(nonatomic) NSDate *enterBackground;
 @property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval enterForeground;

 -(void)viewDidLoad{
         [super viewDidLoad];
         [self subscribeToNotifications];
     }
 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
         [self unsubscribeFromNotifications];
     }
 -(void)subscribeToNotifications{

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appEntersBackground) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appEntersForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    }

 -(void)unsubscribeFromNotifications{

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    }
```

Now that your ViewController knows when the app is entering and exiting foreground, add the methods to start and stop the timer.

```
-(void)appEntersBackground{
   self. enterBackground = [NSDate date];
}
-(void)appEntersForeground{
    self.enterForeground = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceDate:self.enterBackground];
    NSLog(@"%f",self.enterForeground);
}
```

The time spent in background can be accessed by `self.enterForeground`

Comment: Why are you defining your own notifications for this? Get rid of the code in app delegate methods and simply subscribe to the standard (`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`) notifications in the view controller. BTW - those are constants to be used, not string literals.

Comment: @rmaddy Very good point, don't know why I complicated it that much!

Comment: Thanks so much!! I have calculated the time in background. But I have questions about how to jump the condition when it should be after app becomes active. I am doing a skaction which is about fading the color of something. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: @zh_Vincent I am not sure about what condition you are talking about. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Do you know how to fade a fillColor of SKShapeNode by using SKAction? I am in the condition of that. So I am a little lost in how to do that after the app is reactive to enter foreground. I want to know how to jump to the condition after that.

Comment: @zh_Vincent in the `appEntersForeground` function that gets called when you reactivate the app, you should use `customActionWithDuration:block:` and change the `fillColor` of your `SKShapeNode`.

Comment: I know how to do that. What I mean is that how to jump to the condition after app is inactive for a while. It is like in the middle of fading a color and close the app. Also, while I tried your method on my phone, the time that shows when I inactivate the app is wrong. It is 8 hours later than what it should be

Comment: @zh_Vincent, I updated the code. It should be way more precise this way (I tested it earlier and it worked fine). So what you want to achieve is that if your app closes while you're in the middle of `customActionWithDuration:block`, when it gets opened it continues fading from where it left at, right?